# HTML Footer CSS Setup

Tags: html, css

I have wasted too much energy and time trying to create this footer in HTML/CSS, I just can't get it right. I was told the best way of doing this was using `<ul>` and `<li>`'s, but getting it aligning correctly is a challenge!

This is what it should look like
[image: This is what it should look like]

This is what my version looks like
[image: This is what my version looks like]

What I've tried to do is the following: (CSS is below).

```
<div class="footer">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="footer_container">
<ul>
    <li><strong>Title/header</strong>
    <ul>
        <li>Adresse, street</li>
        <li>Tlf: Phone</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li>Zipcode/City</li>
        <li>Mail: Email</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><strong>Links</strong>
    <ul>
        <li>Om skolen</li>
        <li>Galleri</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Elever</li>
        <li>For&aelig;ldre</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right">
        <li>Kalender</li>
        <li>Fag</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>


    .footer { background:url(images/footer_bg.png) top repeat-x #e4e2de; width:100%; padding:20px 0 30px 0; }
.footer ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
.footer ul li { display: inline; margin-left: 25px; }
.footer_container { margin:22px 0 0 0;  }

.footer_container ul { margin:0; padding:0; color:#413f3d; width:100%;  }
.footer_container ul li { display:inline-block; list-style:none; margin:0; font-size:11px; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:0; width:270px; }
.footer_container ul li ul { width:120px; float:left; }
.footer_container ul li ul li { display:block; width:auto; }
.footer_container ul.right { float:right; }
```

I have inserted the 3 images yet as, the 2nd box doesn't look any good.
I'm open to any suggestions/idéas!

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing the `.footer_container` wraps everything above? If so, please add it to the HTML for complete reference. Also, your wrapping `<ul>` isn't closed. More over, what is not aligning properly?

Comment: If anything, I see two lists, but you are trying to make one big list which is just complicating things.

Comment: I apologize for not showing a picture of what it looks like on my computer. I will provide a picture tomorrow when I can access the computer I use for this project. And I forgot to add the whole footer code. I apologize for that, I'll get that fixed tomorrow

Comment: I have updated the main-post with proper informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it up and instead use containers inside the footer instead.

## HTML

```html
<div class="footer_container">
    <div class="container">
        <strong>Title</strong>
        <ul>
            <li>Adresse</li>
            <li>Tlf: Phone</li>
            <li>Zipcode/City</li>
            <li>Mail: Email</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <strong>Links</strong>
        <ul>
            <li>Om skolen</li>
            <li>Elever</li>
            <li>Kalender</li>
            <li>Galleri</li>
            <li>For&aelig;ldre</li>
            <li>Fag</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        Your FB/Twitter things
    </div>
</div>​
```

## CSS

```css
.footer_container{
    width: 960px;
}
.footer_container strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.footer_container div.container{
    width: 320px;
    float: left;
}
.footer_container ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer_container ul li {
    width: 160px;
    float: left;
}
```

## Demo

Over at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atTG9/1/).

Comment: This looks already way better than what I had. Sadly, 2nd box (in the middle" HAS to have 3 rows, like 2 x 2 x 2. As mentioned above, I apologize for not showing a picture of what my version looks like, I will provide that tomorrow when I get access to the PC.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle accordingly, http://jsfiddle.net/atTG9/1/ by adding `.left`, `.middle` and `.right` classes to the containers so I could set a different width on the `<li>` of `div.container.middle`.

Comment: You deserve a medal, thank you very much. It's been really frustrating now being able to make it look right. I definitely learned something from your example. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could help. I recommend you to read (among other things) http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ to understand floats and how they work and how to deal with them since it can be a tricky business, especially when something goes wrong.